# How to ignore Image exif data on a Canvas in Chrome 81+

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, html5-canvas

When I call `context.drawImage` in Chrome 81+ it will auto-rotate the image.  I want to disable this.  I can disable it in an img tag using `image-orientation:none`, but that doesn't work on a canvas.

It seems to ignore the image-orientation style.  In this example below, img tag does not get auto-rotated (as expected), but the canvas does, despite trying to disable it.

How do you prevent `drawImage` from rotating based on exif data, or at least detect that it has done so?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var img = document.getElementById("imgtest");
      // This style is ignored
      img.style.imageOrientation = 'none';
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <img id="imgtest" style="image-orientation:none;" src="portrait.jpg"/>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297"></canvas>    
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to my own problem.  I am using a feature detection library modernizr.com to find out of the browser will automatically rotate images.

```
if(Modernizr.exiforientation) {
  // Browser does the image rotation
}
```

I'd prefer a solution that didn't require a new library, but this works.